# Modern Java Look and Feels

Tags: java, user-interface

I've been looking for a Java Look and Feel (LAF) I can obtain, at a reasonable price (max price: $200), that doesn't look like Windows XP. So far I've found [Synthetica](http://www.javasoft.de/synthetica/), I don't like the standard them, but I like some of the other [themes](http://www.javasoft.de/synthetica/themes/) like the AluOxide or Classy themes.

I want a LAF that's modern looking and not super complex. Something that looks comparable to the SE Beta design (this site's design) would be fine. I want something I do not have to edit or something I only have to make very minor edits to. I need something I may distribute freely in a commercial project without paying royalty.

I like the Nimbus Look and Feel, but I would also like to customize some aspects of it, to make my program look unique. So something like Synth that could be placed on top of nimbus would also be welcome.

Does anyone know of such any such LAFs at no more expensive than $200